# Flip UIView (reversi style)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm trying to make a reversi game, and want to flip a piece to the opposite color. So when a white piece is flipped, it becomes black, and the other way around.

I know you can flip a UIView with the code below, but can't figure out how to flip it to another image.

In my "Piece" class, I have a UIButton with the black or white image. Do I need to create two buttons, and then flip them somehow?

```
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:card cache:YES];
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this to do a transition from the white button to the black button in 0.4s.
You need to have your white and black buttons already as subviews of some other view. For this transition the black button should be hidden before doing the transition.

UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews says that your fromView will be hidden after the transition.

The flip will occur in the whiteButton superview.

```
[UIView transitionFromView:whiteButton 
                    toView:blackButton 
                  duration:0.4f 
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromRight | 
                           UIViewAnimationOptionShowHideTransitionViews
                completion:^(BOOL finished){}];
```